# Altering DBAN files to run automatically

Tags: small-distribution

I am using [DBAN](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/) to wipe some of our hard drives, but I want to speed up and simplify the process.

Is it possible to modify the files in a manner that the 'autonuke' process runs automatically when booted?

I assume this is possible as I have been poking around and found all sorts of config files, but I am not fantastic with this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can modify the ISOLINUX.CFG file in the ISO image to achieve this. Basicly all you have to do is change PROMPT setting to zero like:

```
PROMPT 0
```

It will automatically continue to do wipe, when booted from CD/DVD.

You can also change the mode, which is selected automatically on boot, by changing the DEFAULT setting on the same file. To be sure that the disk will be wiped you can set it to autonuke like this:

```
DEFAULT autonuke
```

**After you have made such disk, make sure that you label it accordingly,
so no one will accidentally wipe their HD.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Don't worry, it will be marked in thick red letters!  I'll give your suggestion a go tonight.

Comment: You can also change mode, which it'll choose automatically by changing the DEFAULT setting in the same file.

Comment: I'm in that file now and it looks like prompt is already zero.

Comment: # Set this option to zero if you wish to skip the boot prompt.
PROMPT 0

Comment: If it is already zero, then it should automatically select boot options. You can try to set that "DEFAULT autonuke" option.